# How can I delete jobs/developer story part of my profile

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I've been a long-time user of the Careers profile, but have not found it useful and had a few frustrating issues that required me to contact StackExchange support to fix with the Careers settings.

I also [don't like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320113/six-user-experience-points-regarding-developer-story) the current Developer Story layout and do not want my information presented in the new Developer Story layout at all.

How can I simply go back to being a Stack Overflow user who does not have any kind of careers/jobs/developer story page at all?

Comment: I second this and this is something that should be easily discoverable.

Comment: I'm hoping to get a support answer for this prior to the Dec 15th deadline when old careers profile data gets auto-imported and/or dropped for a required developer story switchover. Any advice on how to ensure I can delete this aspect of my user profile prior to that time?

Comment: Well I want to +1 on deleting this. SO just kicked me off, forcing me to re-login, and then I was forced to fill out the Dev Story, which I have no interest in. So, now I have a Dev story filled with nonsense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to permanently delete your careers/jobs/developer story, but there are things you can do to hide it and/or remove pieces of it.

**Hide your Developer Story.** You can hide your Developer Story from public view by going to

[Your Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) > [Edit Profile & Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) > [Developer Story Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences).

From this, you can uncheck the

- Privacy > Show the developer story tab; and
- Public link > Always visible

checkboxes. This will hide your Developer Story tab and URLs from everyone but you.

**Update your Job Preferences.** You can alter your Job Preferences as well, by going to

[Your Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) > [Edit Profile & Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) > [Job Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current),

and changing your Job search status as needed.

**Update your Developer Story.** Finally, if you'd like you can go to you Developer Story and delete entries on it. While this doesn't delete the tab it removes any data from it.

While we don't currently have a way to completely delete your Developer Story, it's something that we will consider adding in the future should the demand exist.

Comment: Disabling it from being viewed by anyone but me should be sufficient. Thanks!