# How do I delete my job profile and all asscociated data?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I want to delete my job profile. How do I do it?

Comment: Related? [How can I delete jobs/developer story part of my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338943/1364007)

Comment: It is related, but doesn't help me delete my job profile.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I don't think the linked question is a proper duplicate. The answer there is quite old and the process fails to comply to EU GDPR rules, so I guess an SO Inc. employee need to provided an updated process.

Comment: Contacting StackOverflow Inc. and requesting the deletion of the job profile might work? Contact link is at the footer.